# How do I insert into an existing JSON string

Tags: php

I am building a slack dialog. How can I loop through to dynamically add to the options?

I need to replace the bold with the same lines over and over with different labels and ID.
**['label' => 'xxxxxx','value' => 'yyyyyy'],**

How can I insert this in. Ive tried array() and a few other tricks but obviously I am missing something.

The code below works fine. I just want the options to be something else built on the fly.

```
// Build Dialog
$dialog =
            [
                'callback_id'   => 'approve_recruit',
                'type'          => 'modal',
                'title'         => 'Approve Recruit',
                'submit_label'  => 'Submit',
                'elements'      =>
                                    [
                                        [
                                            'label' => 'Select Recruit',
                                            'type'  => 'select',
                                            'name'  => 'f_recruit',
                                            'options'  =>   [
                                                                [
                                                                'label' => 'xxxxxx',
                                                                'value' => 'yyyyyy'
                                                                ],
                                                            ]
                                        ],
                                        [
                                            'label' => 'Approved',
                                            'type'  => 'select',
                                            'name'  => 'f_approved',
                                            'options'  =>   [
                                                                [
                                                                'label' => 'No',
                                                                'value' => 'No'
                                                                ],
                                                                [
                                                                'label' => 'Yes',
                                                                'value' => 'Yes'
                                                                ],
                                                            ]
                                        ]
                                    ]
            ];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think the [value assigned by reference in foreach](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) loop will help you.
this code will help:

```
foreach ($dialog["elements"] as &$v){
    foreach ($v["options"] as &$c){
        $c["label"] = "somethings as label";
        $c["value"] = "some value";
    }
}

var_dump($dialog);
```

and this is the output:

```
array(5) {
  ["callback_id"]=>
  string(15) "approve_recruit"
  ["type"]=>
  string(5) "modal"
  ["title"]=>
  string(15) "Approve Recruit"
  ["submit_label"]=>
  string(6) "Submit"
  ["elements"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    array(4) {
      ["label"]=>
      string(14) "Select Recruit"
      ["type"]=>
      string(6) "select"
      ["name"]=>
      string(9) "f_recruit"
      ["options"]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=>
        array(2) {
          ["label"]=>
          string(19) "somethings as label"
          ["value"]=>
          string(10) "some value"
        }
      }
    }
    [1]=>
    &array(4) {
      ["label"]=>
      string(8) "Approved"
      ["type"]=>
      string(6) "select"
      ["name"]=>
      string(10) "f_approved"
      ["options"]=>
      array(2) {
        [0]=>
        array(2) {
          ["label"]=>
          string(19) "somethings as label"
          ["value"]=>
          string(10) "some value"
        }
        [1]=>
        &array(2) {
          ["label"]=>
          string(19) "somethings as label"
          ["value"]=>
          string(10) "some value"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is not clear
But if you are looking to access the option value you have to know the array indexes then you can do anything with it

for example look at here

```
$dialog[0]['elements'][0]['options'][0]['label'] = 'BBBB';
$dialog[0]['elements'][0]['options'][0]['value'] = 'CCC';

$dialog[0]['elements'][1]['options'][0]['label'] = 'BBBB1';
$dialog[0]['elements'][1]['options'][0]['value'] = 'CCC1';

$dialog[0]['elements'][1]['options'][1]['label'] = 'BBBB2';
$dialog[0]['elements'][1]['options'][1]['value'] = 'CCC2';
```